# Mysql delete query using more than one condition in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, delete-row

I want to delete data from table (PHP + Mysql), with three conditions. I tried both 'AND' and ',' but don't work.

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `posts-meta` WHERE `post_id` = '$postid' AND `meta_name` = 'post_tag' AND `meta_value` = '$tag'")
```

Is there any way?

Comment: I don't see any mistakes in the shown code. Double check the table and column names and print the result string containing the variable values. Then check if any field in the table actually matches the conditions. (all three values must match exactly)

Comment: I am not sure what you are sorry about. Did this fix the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a query that'll delete the results that match to all three of your conditions, you're query is accurate:

```
DELETE FROM `posts-meta` WHERE `post_id` = '$postid' AND `meta_name` = 'post_tag' AND `meta_value` = '$tag'
```

If you're looking to delete all results matching to either one of your conditions, you should go with OR:

```
DELETE FROM `posts-meta` WHERE `post_id` = '$postid' OR `meta_name` = 'post_tag' OR `meta_value` = '$tag'")
```

Hope I don't offend you by re-stating the obvious with this common knowledge, though your question is really missing context, I have no idea what exactly you're trying to accomplish, why it doesn't work, ...

Answer (score 1):

instead of this ugly way of running queries, stuffing all your code in just one line, always make it sensible, and always add some *error checking*.

If you had a habit of running queries at least this way

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM `posts-meta` WHERE `post_id` = '$postid' 
        AND `meta_name` = 'post_tag' AND `meta_value` = '$tag'";
mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql);
```

you'd been notified of the error and wasted no time of yours and other people.